# How to do an update on only part of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say one has a DataFrame `df1` with `INDEX`, `Column1`, `Column2` and another `df2` with `INDEX`, `Column1`, `Column3`.

Both `INDEX` have similar values so I want to use that to merge the information of one table on the other.

I have been told to do as follows by other users:

```
df1.update(df2, join='left', overwrite=True)
```

This works if both INDEXES have similar values. The result will be df1 will now have `INDEX`, `Column1` (from `df2`) and `Column2` (original from `df1`). `Column3` is not added to `df1` (this behaviour is wanted vs. the "`merge`" command that adds everything).

Now, I would like to update df1 only on a few cases and based on Column2. I thought this would work:

```
df1[df1['Column2'] == 'Cond'].update(df2, join='left', overwrite=True)
```

But it doesn't; sometimes I get an error, other the command works but ALL `df1` values have been modified.

Any idea on how to do this?

PS: Using `.loc` won't work as that requires that whatever INDEX you search for exists and this is not the case.

EDIT: Additional example

```
In [37]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([['USA',1],['USA',2],['USA',3],['FRA',1],['FRA',2]], columns = ['country', 'value'])

In [38]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([['USA',10],['FRA',20]], columns = ['country', 'value'])

In [39]: df1 = df1.set_index('country')

In [40]: df2 = df2.set_index('country')

In [41]: mask = df1['value'] >= 2

In [42]: idx = df1.index[mask]

In [43]: idx = idx.unique()

In [44]: df1
Out[44]:
         value
country
USA          1
USA          2
USA          3
FRA          1
FRA          2

In [45]: df2
Out[45]:
         value
country
USA         10
FRA         20

In [46]: idx
Out[46]: array(['USA', 'FRA'], dtype=object)

In [47]: df1.update(df2.loc[idx])

In [48]: df1
Out[48]:
         value
country
USA         10
USA         10
USA         10
FRA         20
FRA         20
```

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hello jezrael, the example below from unutbu is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 1):

Define the boolean mask

```
mask = (df1['Column2'] == 'Cond')
```

If `df1.index` is *identical* to `df2.index`, then `mask` can be used to select
rows from `df2` -- i.e., `df2.loc[mask]`.  But if they are not identical, then
`df2.loc[mask]` may raise an error (if `len(df1) != len(df2)`), or worse, silently select the wrong rows
because the boolean mask is not aligning index values between `df1` and `df2`.

So in the more general case when the indexes are not identical, the trick is to
convert the boolean mask into an `Index` that can be used to restrict
`df2`.

**If `df1.index` is unique** then call `df1.update` on the restricted `df2`:

```
idx = df1.index[mask]
df1.update(df2.loc[idx])
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[1,2,3], 'Column2':['Cond',5,'Cond']}, index=['A','B','C'])
#    Column1 Column2
# A        1    Cond
# B        2       5
# C        3    Cond

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[10,20,30], 'Column3':[40,50,60]}, index=['D','B','C'])
#    Column1  Column3
# D       10       40
# B       20       50
# C       30       60

mask = df1['Column2'] == 'Cond'
idx = df1.index[mask]
df1.update(df2.loc[idx])
print(df1)
```

prints

```
   Column1 Column2
A        1    Cond
B        2       5
C       30    Cond
```

---

**If `df1.index` is not unique**, then make the index unique by adding `mask` to it:

```
df1['mask'] = df1['value'] >= 2
df2['mask'] = True
df1 = df1.set_index('mask', append=True)
df2 = df2.set_index('mask', append=True)
```

Then calling `df1.update(df2)` produces the desired result because `update` aligns indices.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['USA',1],['USA',2],['USA',3],['FRA',1],['FRA',2]], 
                   columns = ['country', 'value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['USA',10],['FRA',20]], columns = ['country', 'value'])
df1 = df1.set_index('country')
#          value
# country       
# USA          1
# USA          2
# USA          3
# FRA          1
# FRA          2

df2 = df2.set_index('country')
#          value
# country       
# USA         10
# FRA         20

df1['mask'] = df1['value'] >= 2
df2['mask'] = True
df1 = df1.set_index('mask', append=True)
#                value
# country mask        
# USA     False      1
#         True       2
#         True       3
# FRA     False      1
#         True       2

df2 = df2.set_index('mask', append=True)
#               value
# country mask       
# USA     True     10
# FRA     True     20

df1.update(df2)
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel('mask')
print(df1)
```

yields

```
         value
country       
USA          1
USA         10
USA         10
FRA          1
FRA         20
```

Comment: Thanks for this Unutbu!

Comment: what about the case where for instance the index has repeat values. Imagine I had country as index so it could be `USA, USA, USA, FRA` and then `COL1` would be `Cond, 10, 20, Cond, Cond`. My mask would be `[USA, FRA]` and therefore affect all records.

Comment: Could you construct a full example and what the desired result should be?

Comment: added example as you requested

Comment: Interesting question. I've added an alternative method which works when `df1.index` is not unique.